# How to use less than and equal to in an assert statement in python

Tags: python, comparison, assert

When I run the following:

```
growthRates = [3, 4, 5, 0, 3]
for each in growthRates:
    print each
    assert growthRates >= 0, 'Growth Rate is not between 0 and 100'
    assert growthRates <= 100, 'Growth Rate is not between 0 and 100'
```

I get:

```
3
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ps4.py", line 132, in <module>
    testNestEggVariable()
  File "ps4.py", line 126, in testNestEggVariable
    savingsRecord = nestEggVariable(salary, save, growthRates)
  File "ps4.py", line 106, in nestEggVariable
    assert growthRates <= 100, 'Growth Rate is not between 0 and 100'
AssertionError: Growth Rate is not between 0 and 100
```

Why is that?

Comment: `each` is a poor choice for the loop variable. See how you confused even yourself. If you don't want to call the variable `growthRate`, how about `for item in growthRates`?

Comment: @gnibbler I don't see the difference. For (each item) in x seems to be the same for me.  I could see if you argued for for rate in growthRates, that being more useful!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Do:

```
assert each >= 0, 'Growth Rate is not between 0 and 100'
```

not:

```
assert growthRates >= 0, 'Growth Rate is not between 0 and 100'
```

Comment: Better yet, it could be `assert 0 <= each <= 100`.

Comment: I had this syntax originally (with growthRates), but changed it out to troubleshoot it.  I was really confused when one worked and one didn't, but as explained below it makes sense now!  Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

```
assert 0 <= each <= 100, 'Growth Rate %i is not between 0 and 100.' % each
```

Your asserts do not fail of course then, but now the growthRates > 100 because growthRates is list and 0 is integer and 'list'>'integer'.

Comment: +1: This is the only response so far that answers the question -- which was "Why is that?"

Answer (score 4):

`assert (each >= 0)`
not `assert (growthRates >= 0)` :-)

Answer (score 2):

You can also use:

```
growthRates = [0, 10, 100, -1]
assert all(0<=each<=100 for each in growthRates), 'growthRate is not between 0 and 100'

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "any.py", line 2, in <module>
assert all([0<=each<=100 for each in growthRates]), 'growthRate is not between 0 and 100'
AssertionError: growthRate is not between 0 and 100
```

Answer (score 0):

Test for each instead of the list growthRates.

You could also use:

```
growthRates = [3, 4, 5, 0, 3]
testRange = range(0,100)
for each in growthRates:
    print each
    assert each in testRange, 'Growth Rate is not between 0 and 100'
```

Comment: It would be to use range checking (0<=rate<=100) rather than containment testing (i.e. `in`) here because it's more efficient and could easily handle all the possible floating point rates such as 6.789.